# When I post a comment on someones status, sometimes it appears on my friends news feed.

Tags: facebook

When I post a comment on someones status, sometimes it appears on my other friends' news feed. 
I do not want that. Sometimes my friends see something they weren't supposed to see. Something that only my friend and his friends should have seen, not all my friends as well.

How can I prevent this happening? I know that it's a matter of my friend's privacy settings, but is there no way I can prevent this appearing on my friends' neews feed, since there is no way for me to know how the privacy settings are at my friend's page, which just posted the comment to.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change that no.

However, you can see what the privacy settings for that post are. Underneath every post in Facebook is a little icon, showing who can see that post. When you hover over it, it will tell you in more detail what the icon means. A globe means the post is Public (anyone can see it), 2 little persons mean only friends, the same 2 persons, but the right one in a lighter gray means friends except people who you added to the Acquaintances list, a padlock means only you, and a gear symbol means custom settings, which you can figure out by hovering over it.

If your friend has made his post Public, your friends could end up seeing it. If it is Custom, it is also possible they could see it, but it's not sure, unless it tells you when you hover over it. There used to be a *Friends of Friends* setting too, which also allowed your friends to see it, but that seems no longer available.

Comment: Friends of Friends is still available in the Custom dialog; if chosen it has its own icon showing 3 people.